# IPFS file extension for GLB

Tags: ipfs, nft, opensea, js-ipfs, ipfs-http-client

I'm using the `ipfs-http-client` module to interact with IPFS. My problem is that I need the file extension on the link that I generate, and it seems that I can only get it with the `wrapWithDirectory` flag (`-w` with the command line). But this flag makes the result empty so far. The documentation on IPFS is only about the command line, and I've only found out a few tutorials about how to do it, but with other tool than JS, or by uploading folders manually. I need to do it from a JS script, from a single file. The motivation is that I want to generate metadata for an NFT, and a metadata field requires to point to a file with a specific extension.

Full detail: I need to add a GLB file on Opensea. GLB are like GLTF, it's a standard for 3D file. Opensea can detect the `animation_url` field of the metadata of an NFT and render that file. But it needs to end with `.glb`. Translation, my NFT needs its metadata to look like that:

```js
{
  name: <name>,
  description: <description>,
  image: <image>,
  animation_url: 'https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<hash>.glb' // Opensea requires the '.glb' ending.
}
```

The way I do this so far is as follows:

```js
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client';
const client = create({
  host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
  port: 5001,
  protocol: 'https',
  headers: { authorization },
});
const result = await client.add(file); // {path: '<hash>', cid: CID}
const link = `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${result.path}` // I can't add an extension here.
```

In that code, I can put `animation_url: link` in the metadata object, but OpenSea won't recognize it.
I have tried adding the option mentioned above as well:

```js
const result = await client.add(file, {wrapWithDirectory: true}); // {path: '', cid: CID}
```

But then `result.path` is an empty string.
How can I generate a link ending with `.glb`?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution. It indeed involves creating a directory, which is the returned CID, so that we can append the file name with its extension at the end. The result is `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<directory_hash>/<file_name_with_extension>`.

So, correcting the code above it gives the following:

```js
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client';
const client = create({
  host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
  port: 5001,
  protocol: 'https',
  headers: { authorization },
});
const content = await file.arrayBuffer(); // The file needs to be a buffer.
const result = await client.add(
  {content, path: file.name},
  {wrapWithDirectory: true}
);
// result.path is empty, it needs result.cid.toString(),
// and then one can manually append the file name with its extension.
const link = `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${result.cid.toString()}/${result.name}`;
```